# Chemical Potential and Blackbody Radiation

Tags: blackbody

What is the physical significance of the fact that the chemical potential of the photons in a box of volume V is zero ?

Comment: that there are no bound photon states?

Comment: @annav because they don't interact with each other?

Comment: @BMS  yes , photon photon interactions are very improbable and even then are not attractive ( though this last is a supposition on my part)

Comment: Why photons don't interact with each other ?

Comment: In the footnote of Huang's Book, it's being written that the chemical potential is 0 because a photon can disappear into the vacuum.